# Highcharts TreeMap shapeArgs is undefined

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I've been trying to setup a tree map and I've come across a weird error. "shapeArgs is undefined".

I've had a look around and I can't see that anyone else is having this issue and to my eyes there's nothing wrong with that data.

A simple mockup is here (I've stripped out as much as I can);
http://jsfiddle.net/xynrjLzo/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
series: [{
  type: 'treemap',
  layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
  data: [{
    //"id": "D2026",
    "name": "No Data",
    "value": 0
  }, {
   // "id": "D3477",
    "name": "Feel Like °C",
    "value": 33
  }, {
    //"id": "D5514",
    "name": "Feel Like °C",
    "value": 26
  }, {
    //"id": "D5525",
    "name": "Temperature °C Daily Min",
    "value": 22
  }, {
    //"id": "D5940",
    "name": "Temperature °C",
    "value": 13
  }, {
   // "id": "D5942",
    "name": "Dew Point °C",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    //"id": "D5944",
    "name": "Feel Like °C",
    "value": 11
  }]
}],
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This problem is already solved on highcharts github/bugfix branch: http://jsfiddle.net/xynrjLzo/2/ Here you can find information about this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5563

Comment: Great thanks for your help!